# How to list mailbox from Domino Server using LDAP in C#

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

Can anyone suggest me some link where i can get some idea i.e how to list mailbox using LDAP using C#

I am using "Interop.Domino.dll"

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to question #[1238498](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238498/in-c-get-all-the-nsf-filesnotes-database-from-data-notes-directory-and-popul). This is not really using LDAP, but using the Interop.Domino.dll library, can you can open a connection to a Notes server and easily list all Notes "databases" on the server, or in a particular folder. Notes mailboxes are simply Notes databases which happen to be based on a common mail template design. So, you can use the same basic code to loop over all databases, and then add some additional code to filter out only those databases based on the mail template.

```
NotesSession s = new Domino.NotesSessionClass();
s.Initialize("MyPassword");
NotesDbDirectory d = s.GetDbDirectory ("MyServer");
NotesDatabase db = d.GetFirstDatabase();
...

// loop over all DB's
String sPath = db.filePath;
String sTemplateName = db.TemplateName;
// here, you can check if the template name contains "mail", for example
...
db = d.getNextDatabase (db);
...
```