# Connect to Domino server with out name of Database in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, connect, lotus-domino

I'm trying connect to domino server

> **How can i connect to domino server with out name of database**

For example : i have a ip of server 1.1.1.1 . And in domino server i want list all database file (.nsf file).

I was used

```
(NotesDatabase)_session.GetDatabase("1.1.1.1","");
```

But error and i have provide name of database .

Please help me . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use the NotesSession.[getDbDirectory()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETDBDIRECTORY_METHOD.html) method to instantiate a [NotesDbDirector](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDBDIRECTORY_CLASS.html)y object, and then use the NotesDbDirectory.[getFirstDatabase()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETFIRSTDATABASE_METHOD.html) and [getNextDatabase()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETNEXTDATABASE_METHOD.html) methods to iterate through the list of .nsf files.

Comment: i've used code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238498/in-c-sharp-get-all-the-nsf-filesnotes-database-from-data-notes-directory-and